# Javascript calculation won't start/isn't performed correctly

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm making a form in which I want to automate some calculations. The form contains a table with some inputs. The Javascript is below the form. 
For a reason unknown to me, the calculation won't start or isn't performed correctly.

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Inkomsten</legend>
        <table>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Per maand</th>
        <th scope="col">Per jaar</th>
        <th scope="col">Totale termijn</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inkomen</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fldInkomenPerMaand" id="fldInkomenPerMaand"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fldInkomenPerJaar" id="fldInkomenPerJaar" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fldInkomenTotaleTermijn" id="fldInkomenTotaleTermijn" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vakantiegeld</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vakantiegeldPerMaand" id="vakantiegeldPerMaand" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vakantiegeldPerJaar" id="vakantiegeldPerJaar"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vakantiegeldTotaleTermijn" id="vakantiegeldTotaleTermijn" disabled></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function berekeningInkomenPerJaar() {
    var inkomenPerMaand = parseInt(document.getElementById("fldInkomenPerMaand").value);

    var inkomenPerJaar = document.getElementById("fldInkomenPerJaar");
        inkomenPerJaar.value = inkomenPerMaand * 12;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you call the 'berekeningInkomenPerJaar' function?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can call/invoke a function. Apparently, a function doesn't start automatically, as I read on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp. 
I want the function to start/repeat whenever the given input is entered. In this case; 'fldInkomenPerMaand'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your function is not being run when the input is changed.

It is possible to use the JS `addEventListener` function to run your code whenever the input value is changed like so:

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById("fldInkomenPerMaand");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", berekeningInkomenPerJaar);
```

Your original code with the event listener added in:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Inkomsten</legend>
        <table>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Per maand</th>
        <th scope="col">Per jaar</th>
        <th scope="col">Totale termijn</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inkomen</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fldInkomenPerMaand" id="fldInkomenPerMaand"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fldInkomenPerJaar" id="fldInkomenPerJaar" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fldInkomenTotaleTermijn" id="fldInkomenTotaleTermijn" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vakantiegeld</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vakantiegeldPerMaand" id="vakantiegeldPerMaand" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vakantiegeldPerJaar" id="vakantiegeldPerJaar"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vakantiegeldTotaleTermijn" id="vakantiegeldTotaleTermijn" disabled></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function berekeningInkomenPerJaar() {
    var inkomenPerMaand = parseInt(document.getElementById("fldInkomenPerMaand").value);

    var inkomenPerJaar = document.getElementById("fldInkomenPerJaar");
        inkomenPerJaar.value = inkomenPerMaand * 12;
}

var inputElement = document.getElementById("fldInkomenPerMaand");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", berekeningInkomenPerJaar);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```